# How to enable optimizations in opcache (in an official php-fpm docker image)

Tags: php, docker, php-7.2, opcache

The container is built from a trivial Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2.19-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-configure opcache --enable-opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache
```

I did not change php.ini, so all the settings are default.

What's unexpected is that now phpinfo shows (the excerpt):

```
Opcode Caching  Up and Running
Optimization    Disabled
SHM Cache   Enabled
File Cache  Disabled

opcache.enable  On  On
opcache.optimization_level  0   0x7FFFBFFF
```

The question: what else do I need to do to have optimisations enabled?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have to add (COPY) the settings yourself, via `.ini`

Comment: @Ibu nope, php does not need php.ini to run

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, my apologies, I over-simplified the question to a degree when it's impossible to answer it. I'm really sorry for that.

The real reason it's not enabled is because xdebug is installed and enabled as well.